# relation between structure group of holomorphic ,antiholomorphic, complex tangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

I Know that a complex tangent bundle $T_{\mathbb{C}}M$ can be written as direct sum of holomorphic and anti- holomorphic tangent bundles $i. e.$ $T_{\mathbb{C}}M = T_{\mathbb{C}}'M \oplus T_{\mathbb{C}}''M$.I want to know that

(1) ''what would be the relation between structure groups of $T_{\mathbb{C}}M , T_{\mathbb{C}}'M$ and $T_{\mathbb{C}}''M$?"

(2) Can we reduce the structure groups of holomorphic tangent bundle and anti- holomorphic tangent bundle? If yes, to which subspaces of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ they can be reduced?